# CSV manipulation - text removal

Tags: csv, ssis

I'm trying to manipulate a .csv file to remove text at the beginning of the file before the data starts. The file contains a fixed text string followed by a date field, which will change from file to file and then another fixed text string.

eg.

```
"Text1"
"------"
"date"
"Text2"

"data column1","data column2" etc
```

How can I remove this text so i can then use SSIS to import the data to the SQL database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to skip the first line of the file. When you set up the Flat file connection there is an option in the format section of the properties **Header rows to skip:**. You can set this to the number of rows you need to skip and the file should import. If you have a an actual header row you will need to skip that as well and then map the columns manually.

Answer (score 2):

Within the SSIS import configuration, is there not an option to tell SSIS that the "first row has headers," or something roughly similar? That's what I've used when importing through SSIS, at least.